# C# - How to check if a user logged in into a web using HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, http, testing, web, httpwebrequest

I have written a C# function using **HttpWebRequest** that checks if a user successfully logged in to a web and how much time in Milliseconds it took him to log in.
The problem is, that even though I used try and catch, when I enter the wrong Username and Password it's still not going to catch and I can't verify if it succeeded.
How can I check if the user actually logged in successfully?

```
private int[] LoginCheck(string TargetWebApp)
        {
            int[] result = new int[2];
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            try
            {


                string formUrl = "https://XXXXX.com/user/login/default"; // NOTE: This is the URL the form POSTs to, not the URL of the form (you can find this in the "action" attribute of the HTML's form tag
                string formParams = string.Format("email_address={0}&password={1}", "XXXXX", "XXXXX");
                string cookieHeader;
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formUrl);
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                req.Method = "POST";
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
                req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
                using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
                HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;;
                var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                watch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine("Login to WebApp succeed in {0} Milliseconds", elapsedMs);
                cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-cookie"];
                result[0] = 1;
                result[1] = (int)elapsedMs;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Any exception will return false.
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                result[0] = 0;
                result[1] = 0;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are entering the code posted?

Comment: Yes, what's wrong?

Comment: Nothing.  You are not getting any exceptions, and you are getting a response.  So you should be outputting the time.  When you are entering the wrong password you are getting a status of 401 which is the expected response.

Answer (score 3):

You should use below code to get status of response , responseCode 401 is for unauthorized response.

```
var isInvalidAccess = resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
```

Comment: Why is resp.StatusCode is invaild? maybe resp object doesn't have this property?

Comment: Use this ((HttpWebResponse)resp).StatusCode

Comment: Thanks, but I changed WebRequest to HttpWebRequest instead.
Anyway, it still shows isInvalidAccess = false when login success and fails (Like both times..)

Comment: resp.StatusCode = OK

Comment: After providing incorrect password, of your web response is Ok. It means you need fix there and send 401.

Comment: After providing incorrect password, if your web response is Ok. It means you need fix there and send 401.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171051/discussion-between-eilona-and-vikas-chaturvedi).

Comment: You mean status 401? 
I see status OK in the variables both from success and not succuess.
It's not that my Output is OK it's the fact that the actual object getting only OK and I can't play with it